# Where can I get 64 bit OLEDB and/or ADO.Net drivers for Sybase ASE?

Tags: sql-server-2008, 64-bit, sap-ase

I'm new to Sybase and so far it's a monumental pain just to connect to it!  Where in the world can I get 64 bit drivers for Sybase ASE 15 so that I can connect from my 64 bit SQL 2008?  Our Sybase servers are 32 bit and there are no 64 bit drivers on the media :(

Comment: Sybase--3% market share and declining because of crap like this.  Todd's answer is correct; you're going to have to give Sybase significant sums of money to get (really bad) drivers.

Comment: I'm amazed it's 3%.  It seems to be a confused pile of utter junk from what I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 64bit sybase client is licensed separately.
If you don't own any you will need to purchase them or migrate an existing 32bit license to 64bit.